# Find the basis for the kernel of spaces for orthonormal and non-orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

The linear function $f$ is defined as:

$$
f\colon x \in ℝ^n \mapsto (u_1, u_2, \dots, u_k, 0, \dots, 0)^T x \in ℝ^n
$$

$k$ is a fixed integer between $1$ and $n$.

### Questions

1. When $\{ u_i \in ℝ^n \mid i=1, \dots, n \}$ forms an orthonormal basis, find the basis for the kernel.
2. When $\{ u_i \in ℝ^n \mid i=1, \dots, n \}$ forms a non-orthonormal basis, find the basis for the kernel.

### My answers

1. $\{ u_i \in ℝ^n \mid i=1, \dots, n \}$. Given $\{ u_i \in ℝ^n \mid i=1, \dots, n \}$ as orthonormal.
2. I can't even consider it at all.

Comment: I assume you mean $\lbrace u_{k+1},u_{k+2},\dots,u_n\rbrace$ in your answer to $(1)$. Note, however, that this is still wrong. There are many vectors which are not in your basis, for example $u_1+u_2$. Which of those lie in the kernel? And where are you using that the basis is orthonormal?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little? Are you taking $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with the standard "dot product" when you say $\{u_i: 1\leq i\leq n\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$? Also, is $k$ a fixed integer between $1$ and $n$ in the definition of the map $f\colon \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$, that is, $f(x) = (u_1\cdot x,\ldots,u_k\cdot x,0,\ldots 0)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: @krm2233 Thank you. I'll edit this body.